# Calling a ListView update function, from another class... Possible?

Tags: c#, class, delegates

If, lets say I have a FormA with a ListView and an Update() function. Then I also have one Math-Class with a function A() wich does some magic... Can a delegate be used to call Update() from A()? Or Is there a better way? I've realized it's risky to update a gui form from another class.... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Its not that risky as long as the Math class has no knowledge of what its actually calling. You just give it a rough idea by pointing it to the desired function from your Form:

```
public class MathClass {
    public Action FunctionToCall { get; set; }

    public void DoSomeMathOperation() {
        // do something here.. then call the function:

        FunctionToCall();
    }
}
```

In your form you would do this:

```
// Form.cs
public void Update() {
     // this is your update function
}

public void DoMathStuff() {
    MathClass m = new MathClass() { FunctionToCall = Update };
    m.DoSomeMathOperation(); // MathClass will end up calling the Update method above.
}
```

Your MathClass calls Update, but it has no knowledge of the object that told it to call Update or where Update is.. making it safer than tightly coupling your objects together.

Comment: Really nice code! :) I will test this and also from another Thread (as it's the idea)..